# Grails render XML invokes another action from the same controller

Tags: xml, grails

I'm working on Grails 2.4.4 and have an action that renders this way:

```
def subjects = [...]
render(contentType:"text/xml", encoding:"UTF-8") {
  'result' {
     'patients' {
        subjects.each { person ->
           delegate.patient {
              uid(person.uid)
              firstName(person.firstName)
              lastName(person.lastName)
              ...
           }
        }
     }
 ...
```

On the same controller I have a 'getPatient' action, and that action is invoked when the XML render is processed, from this line: delegate.patient

I tried with "delegate" (it seems the delegate there is the controller itself), I tried also quoting the node like 'patient' { ... }, but getPatient is called every time.

Is there a way of making this XML render work **without changing the getPatient action name**?

Comment: I almost didn't believe you at first, but I created a test project and am getting the same behavior.  I'm going to keep digging...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was surprised that the quotations around `patient` didn't work.

The answer is instead of `delegate` you need to refer to `it` or name the argument being passed within the closure and use this.

The `it` in this case refers to an internal class (Document) within the [BaseMarkupBuilder](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/subprojects/groovy-xml/src/main/java/groovy/xml/streamingmarkupsupport/BaseMarkupBuilder.java) class.

```
render(contentType:"text/xml", encoding:"UTF-8") {
    'result' {
        'patients' {
            subjects.each { person ->
                it.'patient' {
                    uid(person.uid)
                    firstName(person.firstName)
                    lastName(person.lastName)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know how you manage to reach the solution, but this is great!